# import cv2 --- ImportError:DLL load failed:

Tags: opencv, python-3.7

I got this error message while trying to run my `main.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  from preview import generate_preview_image
File "C:\abc\python-speed-GUI\preview.py", line 2, in <module>
  import cv2
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py",line 181, in <module>
  bootstrap()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py",line 153, in bootstrap
  native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py",line 127, in <module>
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError:DLL load failed:
```

I installed:

1. **opencv-python 4.8.0.76**
2. **opencv-contrib-python 4.8.0.76**
3. **numpy 1.21.6.**

Environment:

1. Python 3.7.0
2. Windows Server 2012

Comment: Could you add your main.py code please, so we can see where the error might be

Answer (score 1):

OK..I just uninstalled opencv-python, and keep the opencv-contrib-python, and it works...